# how to get values of child object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I've got some nested objects in rails. User -> has_many :tasks -> has_one :location.

Yesterday, I thought I was having trouble linking the location values to the task, but now I realize that I'm not able to get the values to output in show either.

I can get the output via debug

```
<%= for task in @user.tasks %>
        <%= debug task.locations %>
<% end %>
```

outputs

```
--- !ruby/object:Location
attributes:
    id: "1"
    address: "testing address"
    city: "chicago"
attributes_cache:  {}

changed_attributes: {}

etc. etc. etc.
```

So I thought if I used

```
<%= task.locations.address %>
```

Rails would give me the address field. but I get an

```
undefined method 'address' for nil:NilClass
```

any suggestions on what I've got wrong?

---------- update, including models ----------------
My models for tasks & locations are

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :user_id, :date, :description, :location_id

     belongs_to :user
     has_one :location
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :address, :city, :state, :zip

     has_many :tasks
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If task `has_one` location, you'll need to do `task.location.address` without the `s` at the end of location, as `has_one` returns the actual object and not a collection. You'll also need to be sure your location exists before calling it's address method or you'll get an error in case of a nil location. You could be interested in the try method, such as `task.location.try(:address)`.

Comment: I see what you're getting at, and updated the question to show my models.  Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. Is there a way to show what nested models are available, and what rails is expecting re: location or locations?

Comment: Does your task `has_one` location, or does it `belongs_to` a location? If your Task has the location_id in its table, then it `belongs_to` Location. You should change your relation in your Task model, than use `user.tasks.each { |task| task.location }`

Comment: Phew!!  That was a long time, but you solved it! I went down some aweful road and couldn't get back to where things almost worked (forgot to make a new branch). Anyway, you are right about the 'belongs_to'. The reason it seems strange to me is that the locations table is a separate group of locations and the user is making an association to the location, therefore I thought a task has a location, as it doesn't really 'belong_to' a location. I may need has_and_belongs_to_many. The same location will belong to many different tasks. Is that OK?